# Database Schema Conversion from MS SQL 2014 to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I have complex procedures written in MS SQL Server 2014, i need to convert it into mysql routines, is there any tool for this task, i tried mysql workbench and sql lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Tool

[Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant v5.3 for MySQL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42657)

Comment: OP needs to convert MS SQL to MySql

Comment: this tool converts mysql to mssql  only, not from mssql to mysql.

Comment: Try This Link might be helpful for you https://mysqlworkbench.org/2012/07/migrating-from-ms-sql-server-to-mysql-using-workbench-migration-wizard/comment-page-1/